# when does a program halt?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I asked this on StackOverFlow, but they said it would seem better on here.

My question is that is it possible to write a program, P,  that:

- takes an input M, a java program;
- runs forever, and prints out strings to the console.
- And for every x, if M(x) halts, then P(M) eventually prints out x.
- And for every x, if M(x) doesn't halt, then P(M) never prints out x.

Comment: @WillJagy That's incorrect - if $M(x)$ doesn't halt, $P(M)$ just never prints out $x$. This is perfectly doable - at stage $i$, print every string of length at most $i$ for which $M(x)$ halts in at most $i$ steps.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is there a proof that you can give as to why this it true?

Comment: then yes, if "for all $x$" means for all $x$ in a countable set, say $\mathbb{N}$, obviously, running in the same time  all the $M(x), x < N$ and letting $N \to \infty$ will do the trick (BUT $P$ won't halt !)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Fine, make an answer if you like. I think I see your point.  Hmm, evidently you are studying here in town.

Comment: I think the main difference is that for mathematicians (and computer scientists), a program which doesn't halt DOESN'T print anything, a program printing something only AFTER it halted (after it has computed something). in  practice, for programmers, this is obviously dumb, as many programs never halt but print many informations (in an infinite loop)

Comment: @user1952009 Why it is possible to write such a program as I stated above and why it is impossible to write one given an order such as lexicographical order.

Comment: I don't understand the point. if you are a programmer and if $x \in \mathbb{N}$, you know how to write the program in 3 lines : function P(function M) {  x = 0; while (1) { Thread T = new Thread( function() { r = M(x); print(r); } );  x++; } }

Comment: @user1952009 I know. I understand that. But, I am required to prove it. I get this conceptually, but I can't figure out how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: to prove it rigorously, explain how an ordonnancer running $K$ instructions of each thread one after the other will do the trick... what happens if none of the $M(x)$ halts ? (what the computer effectively does ?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, because the set of all inputs for which the program halts is [recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language).  What is *not* possible is to print out every such value in some particular computable order.

Comment: +1. Also not possible: print "$x0$" at some point if $M(x)$ halts, and print "$x1$" at some point if $M(x)$ doesn't halt. It's crucial that the "action" taken in the "doesn't halt" case is really just *no action*.

Comment: Can you expand on both cases(when it is possible, and when it isn't) that you talk about in this answer? Perhaps a proof as to why.

Comment: The idea is to simulate $M$ on all possible inputs in parallel (imagine a main loop that just increments $x$ forever and on each iteration spawns a thread to run $M(x)$).  Whenever one of these instances halts, print $x$.  But for a general program $M$ we can't know in advance how many steps it will take to halt for a given input (because the halting problem is not recursive), so we can't control the order.  But every value of $x$ for which $M(x)$ halts will be listed in the output _somewhere_.

Comment: So what I get from your comment above is that, it is possible to just print out. But if we want to print out in some order, say in lexicographical order, then that is impossible. Correct?

Comment: Correct, because if we could do that, we could adapt that program into a different one that given $(M, x)$ would tell us if $M(x)$ halts or not, and would always halt itself.  But that's impossible by the undecidability of the halting problem.

Comment: So I understand now. But how can I prove these two cases? I assume that I can't just say what I said above. Is there some way to prove this? Does your comment above satisfy as a counterexample for when it is impossible?

Comment: What I've written is an informal proof, or at least the outline of one.  Can you see how to reach a contradiction if the output is always in lexical order?

Comment: I conceptually get the possible case and the impossible case(lexical order). But, I can't seem to write a proof for them.

Comment: Can you add something more that will help me to your answer?